# How do I avoid paying for my own In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I've just had an In-App purchase approved and hit the App Store. To check the app, I've deleted my test copy and downloaded fresh from the App Store - but now I can't get the In-App purchase without paying for it. Is there a way around this? Sandbox user isn't working in the real App Store, and I don't want to make the In-App purchase free, even for a short while, during the first few days of update. Promo codes are available for the app, but not the IAP.

Comment: You can use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).
With this service you can add testers (and yourself) to your app and buy in-app purchases without paying for it.

Comment: Does this work for a live app, or just for pre-release testing?

Comment: This is for pre-release testing. But you can test the same version as you have in App Store (which you send to review team).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below link to create sand box users and test app without paying for it: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is not possible to test (without paying) IAP once app is in app store. For this purpose sandbox environment is provided by apple so that IAP are tested in development.